# cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

O método abaixo que criei na camada model, está me retornando o erro "cannot be cast to java.util.Map"

```
public  List<NotaFiscalProduto> listaItens (boolean entSaid, Date dtinicio, Date dtfim){

    Criteria r = this.session.createCriteria(NotaFiscalProduto.class,"nfp");

    if(dtinicio != null && dtfim != null){

        r.createAlias("notafiscal", "nf");

        r.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ge("nf.dataemissao", dtinicio),Restrictions.le("nf.dataemissao", dtfim)));

        r.createAlias("nf.tipomovimento", "tm");

        r.add(Restrictions.eq("tm.tiponf", entSaid));

        r.createAlias("produto", "pd");

        r.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("nf.notafiscalid"), "notafiscal.notafiscalid")
                .add(Projections.property("nfp.quantidade"), "quantidade")
                .add(Projections.property("pd.produtoid"), "produto.produtoid")
                .add(Projections.property("pd.nome"), "produto.nome")
                .add(Projections.property("pd.preco"), "produto.preco"))
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(NotaFiscalProduto.class));   

        return  (List<NotaFiscalProduto>) r;
    }
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 4):

A variável `r` é uma instância de `Criteria` e não pode ser convertida para um `List`. Na realidade para retornar a lista de resultado você deve utilizar o método `list()` da seguinte forma:

```
return  (List<NotaFiscalProduto>) r.list();
```

> [`list()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#list())
>
> Get the results.

Em tradução livre:

> Obtem os resultados.